# Is null in where statement doesnt returns me rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a complex query. I need to returns me always a row even it doesnt find anything.

```
SELECT 
  a.InventoryItemID,
  a.Name,
  a.RetailPrice,
  b.MainGroupItemCode,
  b.MainGroupItemID,
  c.VatValue,
  a.Code,
  a.Weight,
  b.MainGroupItemName,
  a.RetailPrice2,
  a.FreePrice,
  case when isnull(e.IsActive,0)=1 and isnull(d.price,0)!=0 then d.Price else RetailPrice End  as CustomPrice 
from InventoryMaster a 
join InventoryMainGroupItems b on a.MainGroupItemID=b.MainGroupItemID 
join VatCodes c on b.VatCodeID=c.VatCodeID 
join InventoryPrices d on d.InventoryItemID=a.InventoryItemID 
join InventoryCatalog e on e.CatalogID=d.CatalogID 
where a.InventoryItemID=2 and ISNULL(e.catalogID,1)=3
```

The problem is in last line ISNULL(e.catalogID,1)=3. In my table it doesn't exist CatalogID with number 3.
So it doesnt returns me anything, but there is CatalogID with number 1. I have set that if is null to return me 1, Unfortunately i dont get any row back from my query. How can i fix this ?

My question has been solved i just want to add one more join table with one wheere condition isnide

```
SELECT * 
from 
( 
SELECT t1.ID, 
t1.Name, 

COALESCE(t2.price,t1.Price) AS price , 
Row_number() OVER(partition BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.ID) rn 
FROM InventoryMaster t1 
LEFT JOIN inventoryprices t2 
ON t1.ID=t2.ID 

LEFT join InventoryCatalog t3 
ON t3.ID=t2.ID and t3.ID=2 

where t1.ID=2 
) t 
WHERE t.rn=1
```

it returns me always the retailprice from First Table Inventory

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you're trying to achieve by `ISNULL(e.catalogID,1)=3` if the value of `catalogID` is `NULL` then it isn't 3 (in truth `NULL` does not equal `NULL`) so you can just replace the clause with `e.catalogID = 3`. What you're trying to say in your paragraph below, however, makes little sense I'm afraid. perhaps there's a language barrier here; if so might I recommend asking someone more familiar with English to translate your question, as as it stands it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems you're saying you don't have any rows where `catalogID` has a value of 3, so I would expect that query to never return any rows. It would be like having a clause `WHERE ID = -1` but all every value of your column ID is positive.

Comment: I can give a remote desktop, propably you can better understand what i mean.

Comment: I'm not a consultant I'm afraid (and you have to pay for those).

Comment: That's not problem.

Comment: Try to breakdown your problem to include fever tables, then give the exact scheme of these tables and the data, say what result you expect with that data. See [mcve]

Comment: Also, a must read: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

Add 3 cols near beginning of the select

```
  d.InventoryItemID,
  d.CatalogID,
  e.CatalogID
```

Then remove And ISNULL from the Where, and run to see what you get.

It may be that

```
join InventoryCatalog e
needs 
ON d.CatalogID=ISNULL(e.catalogID,1)
```

Comment: I recommend against `ISNULL` is the `WHERE`/`ON`; it'll make the query non-SARGable. Use proper boolean logic instead/

Comment: Why this doesn't work? where a.InventoryItemID=2 and ISNULL(e.catalogID,1)=3

Comment: How many rows have  SELECT InventoryItemID,  CatalogID  FROM [InventoryPrices]  Where InventoryItemID = 2 and CatalogID = 1